# Theorem 6.2. Topology proof verification.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Theorem6.2.** Let $A$ be a set; suppose that there exists a bijection $f : A   \rightarrow \{1,...,n\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z_+$. Let $B$ be a proper subset of $A$. Then there exists no bijection $g : B \rightarrow \{1,...,n\}$; but (provided $B\ne$$\varnothing$ ) there does exist a bijection $h : B \rightarrow \{1,...,m\}$ for some $ m < n$.

My proof of the first part. Suppose $A$ contains only one element. Then the proper subset $B$ of $A$ is $\varnothing$, so the result is trival. By induction, suppose the theorem is true for $n$,we need to prove it holds for $n+1$. Compare with the bijection $f$ for the integer $n$, there exists a new element $a_0\in A$ such that $f(a_0)  =n+1$, If $a_0 \notin B$,then $B = A$ or $B\subsetneq A $ for the integer $n$, and if $B=A$,then there exist a bijection $f: B\rightarrow\{1,...,n\}$ so there exist no bijection $g : B  \rightarrow \{1,...,n+1\}$; if $B\subsetneq A$,by assumption there exists no bijection $g : B \rightarrow \{1,...,n\}$, So is $n+1$. If $a_0\in B$,then $B\setminus\{a_0\}\subsetneq A$ for the integer $n$ so  there exists no bijection $g :  B\setminus\{a_0\} \rightarrow \{1,...,n\}$  and there there exists no bijection $g : B \rightarrow \{1,...,n+1\}$.
Is my proof right?

Comment: You don’t really need induction for this. Have you tried proving this with contradiction?